# NLog can't write to the log file in the install directory

Tags: nlog

I have an application that logs, and I don't get any file-based logging when I deploy it to the default directory. It seems clear that the reason is that writing to "c:\program files (x86)\blah" requires elevated privelege levels which my app doesn't have. So I end up telling users "install to "c:\blah" and it will work fine, which it does. But that seems rubbish. Any alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could configure NLog to log to a different folder.  NLog has [SpecialFolderLayoutRenderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer) that allows you to use .NET's [special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).  You should be able to specify the log file name using the SpecialFolderLayoutRenderer.  Maybe something like this (I have not tried this):

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate} | ${logger} | "${level} | ${message}" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments:dir=LogFiles:file=${shortdate}.log}" />
```

That should (if it works) create log files in a `LogFiles` subfolder in the user's `Documents` folder, with the actual log file names corresponding to the date.  I don't know, but I would guess that NLog will create the LogFiles folder the first time anything is logged.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked like this:

```
fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/newDMS ClientApplication/Logs/${shortdate}.log"
```